# Buscar el número mayor en un array

Tags: java

Tengo que entregar un ejercicio el cual consiste en declarar un par de arrays con 8 nombres y 8 sueldos, y tengo que mostrar por pantalla el sueldo y el nombre de la persona que más gana. He llegado a hacer esto:

```
package entregaejer;

public class Politicos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double numeromayor;
        int posicion;
        String[] nombres = {"Ivan", "Elena", "Juan", "Sofia", "Jota", "Estela"};
        double[] sueldos = {1500.56, 1456.98, 1010.0, 2000, 1859.05, 2500, 2100.56, 1001.23};

        numeromayor = sueldos[0]

        for(int i=0; i<sueldos.length && i<nombres.length; i++){
//          System.out.println(nombres[i] + " " + sueldos[i]);
            if(sueldos[i]>numeromayor){ // 
                numeromayor = sueldos[i];
                System.out.println(numeromayor);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Como podéis ver, he llegado hasta que el condicional me muestra los valores más alto que la posición 0 del array, pero no consigo caer en cómo poder hacer para que me muestre el número más alto del array.

Aprovecho para comentar que como estoy con DAM, me gustaría aumentar mis conocimientos sobre Java, por tanto, si puedo echar una mano a alguien con algún proyecto suyo, que me lo comente (voy aprendiendo a la par que puedo ayudar).

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Que te muestra la consola? o cual es el error, ahí obtienes el número más alto del array y lo almacenas en número mayor, si lo que quieres es imprimirlo solo vuelvelo a imprimir fuera del for

Comment: Hola Sergio. Gracias por tu comentario, el código tal y como está me muestra los dos números más altos del array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías cambiar de posición la siguiente línea:

```
System.out.println(numeromayor);
```

Tu programa se vería así:

```
for(int i=0; i<sueldos.length && i<nombres.length; i++){
    // System.out.println(nombres[i] + " " + sueldos[i]);
    if(sueldos[i]>numeromayor){ // 
        numeromayor = sueldos[i];
    }
}

System.out.println(numeromayor);
```

Comment: Vaya tela tengo... Ya decía yo que mi planteamiento era lógico (...) Si no saco el println del bucle, difícilmente me lo muestre, jajaja. Mil gracias. :)

Comment: Cosas que suceden cuando uno esta dentro del problema ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Esta es otra forma de iterar que quizas te sirva

```
double[] hola = {5.0, 2.0, 10.0, 3.0};
    double menor = 0;
    double mayor = 0;
    for(double s : hola){
        if (menor>s || menor==0) menor = s;
        if(mayor<s)mayor = s;
    }
```